# Searching for the largest sum interval

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I have consumption data with an hourly step.

```
Date         Hour      Flow
2017-06-01   7         15.25
2017-06-01   8         5.25
2017-06-01   9         16.45
2017-06-01   10        31.25
2017-06-01   11        11.25
2017-06-01   12        25.33
2017-06-01   13        27.28
2017-06-01   14        17.43
2017-06-01   15        19.23
```

I would like to mark the two hours for which the sum is the largest in the day.

```
Date         Hour      Flow     Mark
2017-06-01   7         15.25    0
2017-06-01   8         5.25     0
2017-06-01   9         16.45    0
2017-06-01   10        31.25    0
2017-06-01   11        11.25    0
2017-06-01   12        25.33    1
2017-06-01   13        27.28    1
2017-06-01   14        17.43    0
2017-06-01   15        19.23    0
```

Actual data is over 1000 days.

Thanks

Comment: Hello GrBa, welcome to SO. Could you elaborate. What sum are you referring to? Why are there two marked values on the first of June when the task is to mark the largest sum (which should only exits once unless there is a tie)? Finally, could you share what you have tried so far? That will help everyone what you are trying to do and help us understand where exactly you are stuck. Where exactly does your approach fail? Please help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT[, Mark := {
    f <- Flow + shift(Flow, fill=0)
    i <- which.max(f)
    replace(integer(.N), c(i, i-1L), 1L)
  }, Date]
```

You will need to convert your `data.frame` into `data.table` using `setDT(df)` before using the code above.

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("Date         Hour      Flow
2017-06-01   7         15.25
2017-06-01   8         5.25
2017-06-01   9         16.45
2017-06-01   10        31.25
2017-06-01   11        11.25
2017-06-01   12        25.33
2017-06-01   13        27.28
2017-06-01   14        17.43
2017-06-01   15        19.23")
```

Comment: A perfect solution. that's what I was looking for.
I think I have to switch to data.table

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to find the largest consecutive sum.

Here's a hack way to do it - I'm sure there are more elegant solutions:

```
library(dplyr) 

df %>% 
  mutate(dummy_flow = lead(Flow),
         total = Flow + dummy_flow,
         Mark = ifelse(total == max(total, na.rm = TRUE), 1, 0),
         Mark = ifelse(lag(Mark) == 1 | Mark == 1, 1, 0)) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
  select(-c(dummy_flow, total))
```

Comment: I made a small correction and I have the solution I was looking for.

df %>% 
  mutate(dummy_flow = lead(Flow),
         total = Flow + dummy_flow,
         ) %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  mutate (max_mark = as.integer(total == max(total))) %>% 
  # replace(is.na("."), 0) %>% 
  select(-c(dummy_flow, total))


Thanks 

replace(is.na(.), 0)  --> Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied